# Entity Framework: Junction/Bridge And Child in One Table

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a system which has Members, and a child table of MemberDependents.  A Dependent must always have a parent Member, but a dependent can also be a member themselves.

I model this in the database like so:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MemberDependents(
    ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1),
    MemberID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES dbo.Members (ID) 
        ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE NO ACTION
    MemberObjectID INT -- if not null, this links to what Member they are
);
```

My POCO like so:

```
public class Dependent
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int MemberID {get;set;}          // FK
    public int? MemberObjectID {get;set;}   // optional

    public virtual Member Member {get;set;}         // FK
    public virtual Member MemberObject {get;set;}   // optional
}
```

Using EF's FluentAPI, I map the usual FK relationship:

```
modelBuilder<Dependent>()
    .HasRequired(x => x.Member)
    .WithMany(x => x.Dependents)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.MemberID);
```

... but I'm not sure how to map that optional "this dependent is a member themselves, and that member is..."

```
modelBuilder<Dependent>()
    .HasOptional(x => x.MemberObject)
    .????
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.MemberObjectID);
```

How can I map MemberObject using EF FluentAPI?

**Update:** the (truncated) member model:

```
public class Member
{
    public int ID {get;set;}

    // name, address, etc

    // a few other unrelated properties and methods

    // this is the usual child table
    public virtual ICollection<Dependent> Dependents {Get;set;}

}
```

The Member model has nothing in it to represent this oddball relationship from the Dependent (doesn't seem semantic to put anything in there for it...)

As a side note, I can get away with tossing in a `GetMemberObject()` method in the Dependent and handle it manually, but I'm a bit curious to see how to handle this with EF.

Comment: Can you post the `Member` model?

Comment: @IvanStoev updated accordingly

Comment: Thanks. So `Member.Dependents` is the inverse of `Dependent.Member`. But I don't see the inverse of `Dependent.MemberObject`. You either need to add another `ICollection<Dependent>` and use `WithMany(e => e.SecondCollection)`, or w/o second collection simply `WithMany()`

Comment: @IvanStoev - I hadn't realized I could use WithMany() without an argument.  That seems to do the trick (and makes sense, though I have to load test data to fully confirm). Toss it in an answer and I'll mark it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two `Member` type FK properties in `Dependent` class - `Member` and `MemberObject`, but only one "inverse" `ICollection<Dependent>` type property in `Member` class.

Since you already mapped `Dependent.Member` to `Member.Dependents`, you need to either add another collection like

```
public virtual ICollection<Dependent> DependentOf { get; set;}
```

and map the `MemberObject` to it:

```
modelBuilder<Dependent>()
    .HasOptional(x => x.MemberObject)
    .WithMany(x => DependentOf)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.MemberObjectID);
```

or if you want to keep the relationship *unidirectional* (w/o corresponding collection), EF provides parameterless overload for `WithXYZ` methods specifically for such scenarios (in contrast `HasXYZ` always require argument, so it's important to start the mapping with the entity having the navigation property):

```
modelBuilder<Dependent>()
    .HasOptional(x => x.MemberObject)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.MemberObjectID);
```

Please note that the `WithXYZ` overload used should match the presence of a navigation property, otherwise you will get unexpected surprises.